# React native video player error for wrong size

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am facing a issue in `react-native-video-controls`
First of all here is my code for a single item of the `Flatlist`

```
renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    return(
        <View style={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width*0.9,height:230,backgroundColor:'green',margin:15}}>

            <Text>{item.description}</Text>
            <View style={[
                { width: Dimensions.get('window').width / 2.2 },
                { height: 200,
                  margin: 8
              }]} >
              {
                item.media_type == '2'
                ?
                <VideoPlayer source={{uri:urls.base_url+item.post_video}} 
                style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}} />
                : 
                <Image source={{uri:urls.base_url+item.post_img}}
                style={{alignSelf:'center',height:50,width:'100%',
                overflow:'hidden',borderRadius:40,flex:1}}  />

              }


              </View>

      </View>
    )
   }
```

Basically the item can contain a image / video , So i applied a conditinal checking in the function 
But above line gives me error that .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4xFX.jpg

When i am using `VideoPlayer` without any conditional rendering then it works fine ? What i am doing wrong here ? Please help me !

Comment: Clearly problem is with the width that you are providing to the VideoPlayer which is expecting a number.

Comment: I have also tried setting width to number like 200 but it does not works